# idatareader problem

Tags: idatareader

why My idatareader make error .....?

```
 byteSize = _reader.GetBytes(_reader.GetOrdinal(sFieldName), 0, null, 0, 0);
```

I want to retrive image from database here **sFieldName** is database column Name......it show me **Specified cast is not valid.** message ......what i do?work on c# window vs05....

**sFieldName** is a string ....it's the column name of database and column type is **image** 
My database column name is "BoardImage"

sFieldName="BoardImage"

```
 oBoardDetail.BoardImage =oReader.GetImage("BoardImage");
```

here **oBoardDetail** is a class object and **BoardImage** is a class property type **Image**

Comment: Well, for a start, what type *is* the field?

Comment: If you have no other way to debug, try printing _reader.GetFieldType(_reader.GetOrdinal(sFieldName)), which will give you the Type object corresponding to the column's type. Then, you can correct GetBytes to the appropriate method.

Comment: Please stop asking the same question over and over again, Shamin. If you're not getting the answer you want, update your original question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the column sFieldname is not an Image or VarBinary column.

Please update the missing info on database system, table structure, select statement.